# How to use munmap custom malloc

Tags: c++, c, malloc, mmap

I'm trying to recode malloc and free functions but i got a problem with munmap..

With my custom malloc, I create a pool of memory with mmap (Ex : 4Kb), so I can return an index of this pool as an address when my malloc is called.

This work fine, but when I use my custom free (Call to munmap) then I want to allocate something else with my custom malloc, I got a segfault, like if my ENTIRE pool was disallocated by munmap..

Example:

```
Ask 1024 bytes to my malloc
-> First call so malloc allocate a pool of 4 * pagesize() (So 16 000     
bytes)
-> Return to me an addr than I use. (addr[0] = 42)
-> Free with munmap this address (munmap(addr, 1024))
-> re ask to my malloc 1024 bytes
-> Try to fill it with something and segfault.
```

I don't really understand what is happening. Does munmap delete all my pool ?

Sorry for the poor english..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unmapping the entire page.

> The address addr must be a multiple of the page size. **All pages containing a part of the indicated range are unmapped,** and subsequent references to these pages will generate SIGSEGV. It is not an error if the indicated range does not contain any mapped pages.

[munmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/munmap)

So when you `munmap` your first allocation, you unmapped the entire first page. You should wait to unmap only when the entire page is deallocated.. Or just not unmap at all - Just be sure two processes don't get memory from the same page, so there are no security vulnerabilities.

Comment: So if I ask twice 1024 to my malloc and then I want to disalloc the first, I can't because a page is 4096 on my system ? Am I right ?
But, so, I will have leaks in this case
And in this case, to what deserve the second argument of munmap ?

Comment: @JeanYim You are correct. The second argument is only meaningful if it is more than `PAGE_SIZE` - You can unmap more than one page at a time. You will have fragmentation, but no more than 4K, which isn't that bad. You keep that freed 1024 bytes nearby for the next time the process asks for <=1024. If a user ends up freeing an entire page, you can then unmap it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last question, so the second argument is the number of page to unmap ? Not the number of octet to free ? (I was believed that)

Comment: @JeanYim No, it is the number of bytes to free, but it ends up being rounded up to the nearest page. So, when you pass 1024, it ends up being 1 page, but 4200 would be 2 pages - same as if you passed 9192.

Comment: Ok I see! Thans you very much!